# HTML5 Canvas : How to handle mousedown mouseup mouseclick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I been playing around with html5 canvas and ran into a problem.

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
        dragOffset.x = e.x - mainLayer.trans.x;
        dragOffset.y = e.y - mainLayer.trans.y;
        canvas.onmousemove = mouseMove;
}
canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

canvas.onmouseclick = mouseClick;

function mouseMove(e){
    mainLayer.trans.x = e.x - dragOffset.x;
    mainLayer.trans.y = e.y - dragOffset.y;
    return false;
}

function mouseClick(e){
    // click action
}
```

In this code, I make my mouse click+drag pan the canvas view by translating by the drag offset. But I also have a click event. Right now, whenever I drag my mouse and let go, it runs both onmouseup AND onclick.

Are there any techniques to make them unique?

Comment: Check this out!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224175/html5-canvas-mouse/11027438#11027438

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A *click* event happens after a successful *mousedown* and *mouseup* on an element. Is there any particular reason you are using *click* on top of the mouse events? You should be fine with just *mousedown/mouseup*, *click* is a convenience event that saves you a little bit of coding.

I would generally do it this way:

```
var mouseIsDown = false;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
    dragOffset.x = e.x - mainLayer.trans.x;
    dragOffset.y = e.y - mainLayer.trans.y;

    mouseIsDown = true;
}
canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    if(mouseIsDown) mouseClick(e);

    mouseIsDown = false;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
    if(!mouseIsDown) return;

    mainLayer.trans.x = e.x - dragOffset.x;
    mainLayer.trans.y = e.y - dragOffset.y;
    return false;
}

function mouseClick(e){
    // click action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the function mouse move set a boolean to say that a move occured, encompase all the code in mouseup and click with an if statement to check that a drag did not occur.  After these if statements and before the end of the functions set the dragging boolean to false.

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring a variable such as `clickStatus = 0;` and at the start of each function check to ensure the correct value.

```
if (clickstatus == 0) {
     clickstatus =1;
     ...//function code
 };
```