# JavaScript- how do I use the 'mousedown' to 'select' an image on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mousedown

I have the following JavaScript `mousedown` function, which I'm using to detect when a 'mousedown' has been performed on one of the images I have displayed on an HTML5 canvas:

```
_mousedown: function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    if(obj && obj.shape) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        this.clickStart = true;
        shape._handleEvent('mousedown', evt);
        displayTip(obj.shape.index);

        console.log(obj);
    }
```

As you can see, whenever a 'mousedown' is performed on a part of the canvas which has an object drawn to it, this function calls the function `displayTip`.

The `displayTip` function currently looks like this:

```
function displayTip(index){
    document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[index];
    console.log("displayTip being called");
    console.log("canvasImage id = " + canvasImage.id);
}
```

Now, the `mousedown` function is partially working correctly, in that when it calls `displayTip`, this function then updates the contents of the paragraph `tipsParagraph` to whatever is stored in the `tips` array at the position `index`.However, as you can see, at the end of the `displayTip` function, I have the line

```
`console.log("canvasImage id = " + canvasImage.id);
```

and at the end of the `mousedown` function, I have the line

```
console.log(obj);
```

It is my understanding, that whatever object is detected at the point of the click on the canvas, will be stored in the variable `obj`, as determined by the line

```
var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
```

But in the console, the log at the end of my `displayTip()` function logs that `canvasImage.id` is undefined, and the log at the end of my `mousedown` function logs that the value of the variable `obj` is `[object Object]`

I'm not sure why my `canvasImage.id` is undefined... it should display the ID attribute of the image that the `mousedown` has been detected on... any ideas why this isn't happening?

Presumably, the console log `value of variable obj:[object Object]` means that the mousedown has 'got hold' of the image at the position of the mousedown- so it should display the id of that object shouldn't it?

**Edit 01/03/2013 @ 14:35**

The code for canvas image is as follows:

It is first defined as a global variable at the start of the file, along with all of my other global variables, using the line:

```
var canvasImage;
```

The next use comes within my 'drawImage()' function, where I have used it as follows:

```
var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
      x: randomPosition(0, 950),  //imageX,    //stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: randomPosition(30, 350),  //imageY,    //stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but what I want to do, is use the `mousedown` function to 'get hold' of whatever image the mousedown function is called on, and store that particular image in a variable temporarily, along with all of its attributes (id, width, height, x, y), so that I can access those attributes for use by other bits of code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001283/html5-canvas-how-to-handle-mousedown-mouseup-mouseclick

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question I've asked...

Answer (score 0):

"canvasImage" is not defined, and it's right ! In function you never declare this object.
And for "obj" object, you should try to give us the content... because like that, it's very difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: "canvasImage" has been defined as a global variable with the line `var canvasImage;` at the start of the file... What do you mean about the context of "obj"- the whole of it's use is there in the code sample in my original post, so that's the full context. I'll add in the code for where "canvasImage" is defined now.

Comment: ok, but you say "obj is [object Object]" I mean that could be sweet to have the content of this object to help help you.

Comment: What should be happening when a `mousedown` is detected on an image, is that that image, and all of its attributes (id, height, width, x, y) are stored in the variable `obj' temporarily (i.e. just while the `mousedown` is true), so that I can access that particular image's attributes directly from this variable.

Comment: Because I told you to use "console.log" you must pass only "obj" to the console, not a string:: console.log(obj). That way, you can see each object properties. BTW the markE answer seems to be nice

Answer (score 0):

**Here’s how to access the attributes of your images during mouse events**

Just subscribe to the mouse event you’re interested in and supply a function to call on the event.

The “this” object in your function is the Kinetic.Image object and you can call getXXX() to retrieve whatever attributes you are interested in.

```
        myImage.on('mouseup', function() {
          var att="Id: "+this.getId();
          att+=", width:"+this.getWidth();
          att+=", height:"+this.getHeight();
          att+=", x:"+this.getX();
          att+=", y:"+this.getY();
          att+=", image:"+this.getImage();
          alert(att);
          console.log(att);
        });
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2Qt97/

body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

```
  function initStage(images) {

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var img=new Image();
    var coffee;
    img.onload=function(){
        coffee=new Kinetic.Image({
            x:125,
            y:100,
            name:"Yum!",
            id:"coffeePic",
            image:img
        });
        layer.add(coffee);
        stage.add(layer);

        coffee.on('mouseup', function() {
          var att="Id: "+this.getId();
          att+=", width:"+this.getWidth();
          att+=", height:"+this.getHeight();
          att+=", x:"+this.getX();
          att+=", y:"+this.getY();
          att+=", image:"+this.getImage();
          alert(att);
          console.log(att);
        });

    }
    img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/coffee.png";

  }
  initStage();

</script>
```