# canvas: onMouseDown is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom

After window finished loading, I want to add some Javascript to the canvas. I tried this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.addEventListener("load", init);

  function init(){
      var canvas = document ...
      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
  }

</script>
```

But I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: onMouseDown is not defined
```

Comment: Why do you think `onMouseDown` should be defined? You haven't defined it anywhere in the code you have written in the question.

Comment: I was not familiar enough with addEventListener. The confusing point was when to use "on" and when not. I can call canvas.onMouseDown = function(e) { ... } but The event is called "mousedown". I didn't know, that "mousedown" is the event. I though I would need to implement "mousedown" and "onMouseDown" is the 'event'.

Comment: You can call your function whatever you like. `onMouseDown`, `mousedown`, `function_to_fun_with_the_mouse_is_down_that_makes_it_rain_puppies`. You still need to define the function you want to run when the event happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a function for `onMouseDown` like

```
function onMouseDown() {
// Perform mouse down functions you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `onMouseDown` function is not defined or it's not loaded on the current html file.

You can make sure by opening the debug console in your browser (press F12 in and click on Console tab) and check whether your function exists or not. You just need to type `onMouseDown` on the browser console and watch the result. If you got `RefrenceError`, it does mean your function has not written or has not loaded yet.

[As you see here, the onMouseDown function hasn't defined on the current document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng1hq.png)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but writing the function directly helped:

```
function init(){
    var canvas = document ...
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
        // bla
    }
}
```

As in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036499

Comment: You can also use `canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);`, you just have to define the function somewhere e.g. `function onMouseDown(event) { //code here }`. The even listener is looking for a function with that name and not finding it which is exactly what the error is telling you.